# Setting destination port with TCP socket

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

In the case where the source port and destination port of a non-blocking TCP socket are not in agreement(for a p2p application), how does one specify the destination port that the socket will Connect() to?

Comment: What do you mean, "not in agreement" ? In the TCP protocol, the source port and the destination port are unrelated numbers. E.g. the destination port for HTTP is generally 80, but the source port can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

In case of P2P the clients first connect to torrent to get a list of peers(seeders) and the port number which is open at the peer. The system which wants to download will then connect to the peer using the address and port provided by the tracker.

The peers are not restrictive(generally) and accept connections from any source address or ip

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the destination port of a connection is done in the sockadder-struct that you pass to the connect()-call. Since you don't specify which OS you are working on, in it is difficult to provide a concrete example. However, for both Linux and Windows, you would typically load the sockaddr-struct using getaddrinfo(). A nice Linux-example is provided [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getaddrinfoman.html), while MS has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in their official documentation.

Comment: Kristian: I'm using Windows AND Linux Ubuntu 12.10 as this application will have versions for both OS's.

Comment: Ok. The signature for getaddrinfo is very similar, so with some small #ifdef WINDOWS/LINUX, your code should be platform independent.